# gsub in Lua. Unable to replace pattern

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I want to replace all phrases `$br$` in the string for the character `'\n'`.

I write the following code: `str = string.gsub("String 1 $br$ String 2", "$br$", "\n")`.

But this does not work and displays the string `String 1 $br$ String 2`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the `$` character since it represents the end of line.

```
str = string.gsub("String 1 $br$ String 2", "%$br%$", "\n")
```

If you want to grab the whitespace around `$br$` as well:

```
str = string.gsub("String 1 $br$ String 2", "%s*%$br%$%s*", "\n")
```

Comment: Link to Lua patterns documentation: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1